# SBT получить имя файла в каталоге по паттерну

Tags: scala, sbt

Я использую плагин sbt-conductr, при выполнении таски bundle:dist генерится файл формата name-0.1-snapshot-34234lkm4klnln....34fdgdsg.zip в директории /target/bundle, этот zip архив я хочу опубликовать в artifactory, для этого мне необходимо выполнить addArtifact, но т.к. часть имени файла (34234lkm4klnln....34fdgdsg) генерится каждый раз разные мне необходимо находить имя файла во время выполнения build.sbt

```
//in build.sbt
val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("return the bundle:dist-zip file")

myZipTask := {
    val filesArray = new java.io.File("/target/bundle").listFiles()
    //тут мне нужно получить значение из filesArray по паттерну, как?
    file(fileName)
}; addArtifact( Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask)
```

Так же я пробовал выполнить это следующим образом:

```
val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("return the bundle:dist-zip file")

myZipTask := {
  import java.io.File

  def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[String] = {
    val file = new File(dir)
    file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
      .filter(_.getName.startsWith("startName"))
      .map(_.getPath).toList
  }
  getListOfFiles("/target/bundle")
}; addArtifact( Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask)
```

на что получил ошибку:

```
build.sbt: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[String]
required: sbt.File
(which expands to)  java.io.File
getListOfFiles("/target/bundle")
              ^
```

Что я делаю не так?
Есть ли возможность отключать этот префикс при создании файла?

Comment: так в ошибке же все сказано: нужено использовать тип `File`, а вы используете `String`. Попробуйте `getListOfFiles(new File("/target/bundle"))`

Answer (score 0):

Если цель в том, чтобы просто добавить сгенерированный файл к списку публикуемых артефактов, то можно получить ссылку на файл от самого `bundle:dist`:

```
addArtifact(
  Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), 
  (dist in Bundle).value
)
```

Comment: Это не работает:
`build.sbt:111: error: overloaded method value addArtifact with alternatives:
(artifact: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.librarymanagement.Artifact],taskDef: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[java.io.File]])sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition <and>
(a: sbt.librarymanagement.Artifact,taskDef: sbt.TaskKey[java.io.File])sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition
cannot be applied to (sbt.librarymanagement.Artifact, sbt.File)
addArtifact(
^`